# Open file with on skydrive with knowledge about relative path (javascript)

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I have a textfile on a cloud-storage (in my case skydrive/onedrive , however I wouldn't care to use another). In this text message there is information about the relative path to other files (e.g. file1 =  /journals/2014/pdf/example.pdf).

What I would like to do is, load the information of the textfile from the cloud storage and create links to the corresponding files on the cloud storage.

Since the cloud-storages work with certain IDs I, I don't know whether its possible to combine the folder of the ID with the information of the relative path.

I am using java script, but didn't find any information on this topic in the api documentation

Thanks in advance.